MOSFETs keep breaking
I'm trying to build an electrical erosion machine. I need create a circuit capable of generating a 100 V square wave output signal, with variable frequency (10-100 kHz) and duty cycle.

I built a test circuit to the test concept but I'm having problems with my MOSFETs.
The IRFP260 are rated for 200 V and 50 A but even at a lower voltage generated from a lab PSU of 24 V limited at 0.5 A, as soon as I send the signal to the gate, the MOSFET dies (permanent low ohmic value between drain and source).
On the oscilloscope I get a very clean 12 V PWM signal from the gate driver up to the gate.
The reading at drain is a total mess and, after testing, if I stop the 5 V PWM signal, the drain-source remain in a conductive state.
I also tried putting various resistors before the drain, an LED, but the results are always the same... LED lights up, duty cycle and frequency changes do not translate correctly on the LED side, readings on the oscilloscope are nonsense, MOSFET gets stuck in conductive state, even with no signal at the gate.

I know this is a stupid question, but: the IRFP260 has a bit of a surprising pin layout. You double-checked you're not connecting gate to what you think is drain or source?

Hi, i don't find your question stupid at all, someone could really overlook this and it's good you pointed it out... i was aware of the weird pin configuration however and did double/triple check before and after the first fails, so i don't believe this is the problem i' having.

@MarcusMüller Are you confusing it with a different one? The IRFP260 has the standard GDS pinout.

What are the exact characteristics of your load (R4), including inductance? Note that mere wire and trace length constitute significant inductance at these rates of dI/dt.

Along with Tim's comment, it won't hurt to place a diode from the FET drain to the 100V supply. This will clamp the drain voltage at 101 V or so. It should be a part that can tolerate the full supply voltage, full load current and should switch off fast (ideally a Schottky)

Also what do you hope to achieve with the MIC4422? The slightly extra turn-off dI/dt is likely part of your problem. So it might already be enough, to just remove the MIC4422 and drive the gate directly from the FOD3182. Alternatively you could remove the FOD3182 if you don't need isolation.

@TimWilliams, Erosion machines work by basically shorting an electrode to the part, the wires currently are around 0,5m (20"). Current is normally regulated with power resistors or in my case using the lab psu (i checked, when shorting i do get only 0,5 amps)

@tobalt, the FOD3182 is for isolating my microcontroller and laptop...the MIC4422 is there because it can output 9A, while the FOD can do only 3A. If the circuit eventually works i would like to use more FETs in parallel to achive bigger power at the output... this however requires more current for the gates.

If you assume 1e8 A/s, and 1e-6 H inductance (not unreasonable, actually probably too optimistic), you are looking at 100 V of flyback voltage (in addition to 100 V supply voltage). So without a flyback diode, it is pretty likely you are exceeding the drain-source-voltage abs. max. ratings.

@tobalt, you are right... i can correct this with a diode, and maybe higher rated mosfets... but why are the current one dying at 24V... i managed to kill it even with 6V from the lab psu...

depending on what is inside the wire loop the inductance can be much higher. it's not unreasonable to induce 200 V transiently with super hard turn-off even at "low" currents.

First of all add the flyback diode. Then post a scope screenshot of the drain. Also up the gate drive resistor a lot and loose the diode (for now). Maybe 300 ohms. Driving the gate hard introduces a lot of parasitic issues so you only want to drive it as hard as you need to.

Based on comments, here is an equivalent circuit of your setup:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When turning on (and if R1 is a resistor as given), this draws a peak up to 20A -- much more than the 0.5A nominal.
Note that supplies almost always have a big fat capacitor on their output (open yours up to check, doesn't hurt).  This often doesn't serve much or any purpose, that couldn't be solved with better design of the control circuit behind it (in effect, controlling ideal diode D1's voltage drop and reaction time), but you see it very often nonetheless.  So, at least for short periods (less than the R1*C1 time constant, 10s µs at least), and without further information, we should assume the supply is a steady 100V.
The IRFP260 is a big transistor.  It can handle 100V / 5Ω = 20A just fine: the 55mΩ on-resistance drops 1.1V and dissipates 22W, easily heatsinked if this is endured continuously.  (Or a bit more as temperature rises, but still nothing outside of limits, as long as Tj(max) is respected.)
There may be other power dissipation, though.  At turn-off, L1's energy (let's assume 20A peak again) is delivered into the drain via avalanche breakdown.  It might store ballpark (1/2)(0.5µH)(20A)^2 = 100µJ, delivering a flyback pulse of probably 240V or so (typically it's 5-40% above the actual rating; all the datasheet guarantees is no breakdown at the rating), which is boosted by the 100V supply to about 170µJ at the transistor.  Which isn't much by itself, but at say 10kHz, that's 1.7W, starts to get noticeable.
IRFP260, at least Vishay's version of it, and the original is rated for repetitive avalanche.  (The current version Infineon datasheet seems ambiguous, rating avalanche current, but not repetitive avalanche current.)  Most modern MOSFETs are not; this part, and parameter, is a relic of the old days when MOSFETs were new, and finally just competitive with BJTs.
After many generations of process optimization, modern MOSFETs place the gate oxide very close to the avalanche center.  This is a problem, because avalanche discharge consists of high energy electrons and holes, which diffuse through the immediate area (100s nm?), losing energy to collisions until settling down as regular (thermalized) conduction band (or valence holes) charges.  When gate oxide is near the breakdown location, these high-energy charges can get lodged in it, shifting threshold voltage very slightly, but more importantly, causing eventual breakdown of the oxide and subsequent failure of the device.
A legitimate or classic IRFP260 should be able to withstand this service, as long as power dissipation and junction temperature are respected.  It's rated for repetitive avalanche up to 46A peak, and pulses as often as junction temperature dictates.  If you have a modern substitute (or counterfeit) instead, it likely isn't as robust.
There are other quirks to watch out for.  The spark itself takes a mere fraction of a nanosecond to close; this launches an EM wave up the wires, and if the layout of the turn-off switch and related circuitry isn't well made, stray inductances in them in turn, drop substantial voltage, perhaps causing invalid or destructive gate voltage, disruption or destruction of drive circuitry or control logic, etc.  Considering the equivalent circuit above, suppose that a sudden step change occurs in series with R1 say, and that change propagates out along L1, the corresponding inductance in the ground path to the supply, that between V2 (the driver and its supply), and along capacitances between all these locations, across isolation barriers, capacitance to surroundings, etc.
In summary: the transistor is probably fine, if it is what it says on the label.  If not, it may fail rapidly (vastly undersized), or eventually (seconds to months?).  There are possible details about the resistor that may be relevant, or control circuit.
As for flyback, a modern transistor can be protected with a snubber, clamp or TVS:

simulate this circuit

Which one you'd choose depends on application, and is worth researching under these keywords.
